# Convert 'System.Data.DataRow[]' to 'System.Data.DataRow'

Tags: c#-4.0

I Have a DataTable in ViewState and the same DataTable is used to Data Bind a Gridview which have  Template Columns and calculated fields

Now when User press a Button All the Records from the Datatable of the selected Row (Checkbox)Should be copied to another data table

```
   public void GeneratePO1()
    {
        // get the datatable from Viewstate
        DataTable myDS = (DataTable)ViewState["BomData"];

        //create a new datatable to store New Selected Items
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //clone the schme of the Orginal Datatble to new one
        dt = myDS.Clone();

        //Loop through each gridviewrows to find the Rows where checkbox column is checked
        foreach (GridViewRow di in tbl_bom.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)di.FindControl("chk_select");

            if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
            {
                //get the uniqueID of that row
                int skudetpk = int.Parse((di.FindControl("lbl_skudetpk") as Label).Text);

                //create a new datarow for dt
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                //query the orginal datatable and put it in new data row
                dr = myDS.Select("SkuDet_pk=" + skudetpk + "");//Error occurs here

                //add the datarow to datatable
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            }
        }

        Session["ItemforPO"] = dt;
    }
```

I am getting the below  error msg

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataRow[]' to 'System.Data.DataRow'

Comment: *Where* are you getting that error? Please edit your question so that the code is properly indented, too - it's all over the place at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for in conveniance   dr = myDS.Select("SkuDet_pk=" + skudetpk + "");//Error occurs here

Comment: Right. Well, what does `DataTable.Select` return? A `DataRow[]`. So you can't assign that to a *single* `DataRow` variable. (It's not clear why you're calling `NewRow()` at all, by the way... or `new DataTable()`. In both cases you're throwing away the newly-created object.) What do you want to happen if there is more than one row that matches your query?

Comment: Hy Jon I am Aware that the issue is  cannot assign a DataRow[] (array) to DataRow object. But My requirement is like that ..I may have many rows selected so

Comment: You may have many rows selected, so... what? How do you expect to handle that situation with a single `DataRow` variable? (Hint: you probably want `foreach`.)

Comment: query will always return a single row as Skudet_pk is primarykey..I want the Code to loop through the selected rows and get the skudet_pk and run the query  and save the result in another database..So that I can send it to another page...Iam  trying this now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309370/filter-a-data-table-with-values-from-an-array-c-sharp...

Comment: Well, you could use `dr = myDS.Select("SkuDet_pk=" + skudetpk + "").Single()` then, to validate that there's only a single row.

Comment: Thanks for your help .It was a great solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion of Jon Skeet .I had added .Single() tio the datatable and then Instead of Adding the Row I had imported the row. That solved My issue

```
 public void GeneratePO1()
        {
            // get the datatable from Viewstate
            DataTable myDS = (DataTable)ViewState["BomData"];

            //create a new datatable to store New Selected Items
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            //clone the schme of the Orginal Datatble to new one
            dt = myDS.Clone();

            //Loop through each gridviewrows to find the Rows where checkbox column is checked
            foreach (GridViewRow di in tbl_bom.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)di.FindControl("chk_select");

                if (chkBx != null && chkBx.Checked)
                {
                    //get the uniqueID of that row
                    int skudetpk = int.Parse((di.FindControl("lbl_skudetpk") as Label).Text);

                    //create a new datarow for dt
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                    //query the orginal datatable and put it in new data row
                    dr = myDS.Select("SkuDet_pk=" + skudetpk + "").Single();//Error occurs here

                    //import the datarow to datatable
                    dt.ImportRow(dr);

                }
            }

            Session["ItemforPO"] = dt;
        }
```